# Can I use a 20V or 24V to power up a piano that needs 21V?

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, ac-dc

The power adapter of the piano should be AC/DC 21V, 1.5A.

But I can't find in a short time to buy something exactly like that, but I found this options:

- 20V, 3A or
- 24V, 3A

Can I use one of this to power the piano or it's not ok?

Comment: Chances are it's not ok.

Comment: Try the 20V one and it should work. The piano probably has tolerance for input voltage like 5% or something. Do not try the 24V one, it would most likely fry the piano circuit board. Another thing you should note is the DC jack polarity, most are center positive.

Comment: @Kokachi: Many older things that called themselves "21V" supplies would output more than that under lightly-loaded conditions.  Unfortunately, neither power supplies nor the devices they feed are very well specified, so it's hard to know what supplies will safely used with what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference of 1.5A or 3A does not matter. I.e. the adapter should be at least the Amperage requested (>1.5A).

However, for the voltage, it should in principle not be exceeded. As Kokachi wrote, first try 20V.

If you dare to try 24V (not advised), you run into the risk of burning the piano's electronics. But even if not (immediately), it results in more heat, which reduces the lifetime (probably).

Also check the polarity, if needed you can easily change this by resoldering the adapter cables.

Comment: Surely if the original adapter is specified as AC/DC the polarity wouldn't matter?

Comment: @Finbarr True, but the poster mentions some options, so those are not the original adapters (otherwise the voltage would probably show the exact requested 21V as well).

Comment: @Finbarr  looking at the nature of the question one can assume that the OP actually meant AC to DC.

Answer (score 5):

*20V, 3A* specifies that 3A is the max. current you can draw from that adapter. The piano may need only 1.5A at 21V. It should work with 20V. But if you are planning to use *24V,3A* adapter, DC-DC buck converter might be needed to stay on the safe side.